# ng-click value change + $scope.watch bind not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-watch

I have a scope variable '$scope.searchType' which is equal to 'createdAt' by default. In my HTML I have options that change the scope variable value:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a ng-click="searchType = 'Anything'">Anything</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="searchType = 'Payment'">Payment</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="searchType = 'Total'">Total</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="searchType = 'Tax'">Tax</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="searchType = 'Payment Method'">Payment Method</a></li>
</ul>
```

In my controller I have the following to listen for changes:

```
$scope.$watch('searchType', function(newValue) {
    if(newValue == 'Payment') {
        $scope.searchTypeFilter = 'id';
        $scope.searchFiltered = true;
    } else if(newValue == 'Total') {
        $scope.searchTypeFilter = 'total';
        $scope.searchFiltered = true;
    } else if(newValue == 'Tax') {
        $scope.searchTypeFilter = 'tax';
        $scope.searchFiltered = true;
    } else if(newValue == 'Payment Method') {
        $scope.searchTypeFilter = 'paymentType';
        $scope.searchFiltered = true;
    } else {
        $scope.searchTypeFilter = '';
        $scope.searchFiltered = false;
        $scope.search = '';
    }
}, true);
```

For some reason the $scope.$watch never gets called. I cannot figure out how this doesn't work since it used to. This is the '$scope.searchType' declaration:

```
$scope.sortType = 'createdAt';
```

Comment: does your `dropdown-menu` html is wrapped in the controller where you putted a `$watch`?

Comment: are you sure the watch and the dropdown menu are within the same scope?

Comment: Yes, I believe they are since the $scope.$watch enters once on page load. It never gets run again after that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add a $watch because you have a click event that will set your filter variable.

Also your if/else can be simplified with a js object.

Please have a look at the demo below or this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/xvz3qbg1/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
.controller('mainController', MainController);

function MainController($scope) {
    var filterMapping = {
        
        Payment: 'id',
        Total: 'total',
        Tax: 'tax',
        'Payment Method': 'paymentType',
        Default: ''
    };
    
    this.setNewFilter = function(name) {
        $scope.searchTypeFilter = filterMapping[name] || filterMapping['Default'];
        $scope.searchFiltered = $scope.searchTypeFilter != '' ? true: false;
    };
  
    this.setNewFilter(''); // init filter to anything
}

MainController.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController as ctrl">
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a ng-click="ctrl.setNewFilter('Anything')">Anything</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="ctrl.setNewFilter('Payment')">Payment</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="ctrl.setNewFilter('Total')">Total</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="ctrl.setNewFilter('Tax')">Tax</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="ctrl.setNewFilter('Payment Method')">Payment Method</a></li>
</ul>
    {{searchFiltered}}<br/>
{{searchTypeFilter}}    
</div>
```

Comment: As an aside - why wouldn't watch work in this situation?

Comment: Watch would work here too. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/1u007t1s/). I don't know what was wrong in your code. Anyway, I wouldn't add a watch here because it can slow your app down if your app is getting larger. Because it will be checked on every digest loop.